# How to code triple sum without three nested loops

Tags: java, arrays, iteration, time-complexity

I am trying to efficiently implement a formula like:

```
sum(i=1,n) sum(j=i+1,n) sum(k=j+1,n) x(i)*x(j)*x(k)
```

The straightforward way to do this is something like:

```
sum = 0
for (int i=1; i<n; i++ )
    for( int j=i+1; j<n; j++ )
        for( int k=j+1; k<n; k++ )
            sum += x[i]*x[j]*x[k]
```

The problem is that this is `O(n^3)`.  I'm wondering whether there is some way to rewrite this
so that I can eliminate one or even two layers of iteration, using some recurrence relation.  I tried the following, but no luck:

```
for (int i=n; i>0; i-- )
    int sumK = 0
    for( int j=n; j>i; j-- ) {
         sum += sumK
         sumK += x[i]*x[j]*x[j]
    }
```

It gives a different answer than the straightforward code, but it does eliminate one layer of iteration, so I *think* I'm on the right track (albeit derailed).  Can someone help?

Answer (score 5):

You start with this formula formally written:
[image: formal equation]

The first observation to make is that since x_i and x_j are constant relative to k, and they're being multiplied, you can factor them out of the summation, leaving you with:
[image: pulled out]

Using the same logic, you can pull the x_i out of another summation:
[image: pulled out more]

Now, you can see that you just need to calculate the sum of the elements in x from i..n for every `i < n` (which can be done in O(n) time using suffix sums), making sure to multiply by the element that you started on, to account for the multiplication with x_j. This accounts for the rightmost summation. Now, you can do the same thing but for the sums you got previously, making sure to multiply by the value of the element you start at (to account for the multiplication by x_i). This accounts for the middle summation. Then, you can just sum up all the values from 1 to n of the previous results, giving you the final answer. Here's the resulting java code (look at function `fastProduct`):

```java
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {
    public static void printArr(long[] arr) {
        System.out.print("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
            if (i < arr.length - 1) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }

    public static long naiveProduct(long[] arr) {
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j ++) {
                for (int k = j + 1; k < arr.length; k ++) {
                    sum += arr[i] * arr[j] * arr[k];
                }
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static long fastProduct(long[] arr) {
        long[] sums = new long[arr.length];
        sums[arr.length - 2] = arr[arr.length - 1];
        // pre-calculate the summations of x_k
        for (int j = arr.length - 3; j >= 1; j --) {
            sums[j] = sums[j + 1] + arr[j + 1];
        }
        // multiply by x_j
        for (int j = 1; j <= arr.length - 2; j ++) {
            sums[j] *= arr[j];
        }
        long[] sumSums = new long[arr.length];
        sumSums[arr.length - 3] = sums[arr.length - 2];
        // pre-calculate the summations of x_j times the summation of x_k
        for (int i = arr.length - 4; i >= 0; i --) {
            sumSums[i] = sumSums[i + 1] + sums[i + 1];
        }
        // multiply by x_i
        for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length - 3; i ++) {
            sumSums[i] *= arr[i];
        }
        long total = 0;
        // sum up the final summation
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 2; i ++) {
            total += sumSums[i];
        }
        return total;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long[] test = new long[10];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i ++) {
            test[i] = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
        }
        printArr(test);
        System.out.printf("%d %d", naiveProduct(test), fastProduct(test));
    }
}
```

Comment: Aplet123, thanks, but I'm not sure I follow.   I think what you're saying is that each of the three summations is O(n), so the product is O(3n), which is simply O(n).   However, consider the third summation, for example.   Because k runs from j+1 to n, that summation is actually a function of "j" as well as the Xk's, so in reality, there are actually n different summation results (one for each j), and so what you've got, I think, is O(n)*O(n)*O(n) or O(n3).   However, I maybe I'm not following your suggestion correctly; could you please add some (pseudo)code to illustrate your suggestion?

Comment: Nice!   And apparently O(n) due to concatenation (not nesting) of multiple O(n) loops.   The key, it seems, is that you make explicit the variability of the inner sums by maintaining an **array** of sums rather than a single sum.   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following update is based on [earlier Aplet123's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64637814/13279831), it allowed to reduce complexity by removing one nested loop due to reusing the innermost sum on `k`:

```java
static int sum3_fix(int[] x) {
    int sum = 0;
    int tmp = 0; // sum of innermost loop, will be reduced for the following iterations
    int n = x.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        int tmp2 = 0;
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++ ) {
            if (tmp == 0) { // calculate sum of x[2,n] only once
                for(int k = j + 1; k < n; k++ ) {
                    tmp += x[k];
                }
            } else {
                tmp -= x[j];
            }
            tmp2 += x[j] * tmp;
        }
        sum += x[i] * tmp2;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Tests:

```
int[] x = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 15, 20};
System.out.println(sum3(x));  // non-optimized implementation
System.out.println(sum3_fix(x));
```

Output

```
55506
55506
```